# CRUD application embedded in wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, constructor

I have found an excellent CRUD building tutorial: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud3.php

I have followed the instructions, and created one for my needs. (The db is the same as what the wordpress uses.) The correctly working example can be seen here:
http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/wp-content/themes/constructor/index2.html#

Now I would like to embed this to a wordpress page. I use a custom page template, where I hardcopy the code used in the working example to the container part of the page. It can be seen here:
http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/kapcsolati-vazlat/#

As you can see, this is rendered wrong, and does not work (not showing the data, not able to save etc.). The two pages use the same files (ex. save_user.php is the one and the same in both instances.) I use Wordpress with the Constructor theme.

Please help me solve this problem. **How can I correctly insert this working example to my wordpress page?**

Thanks for the help,
Sziro

Answer (score 0):

It actually works with iframing the said html.

```
<iframe name="FRAME2" src="http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/wp-content/themes/constructor/index2.html" frameborder="1" width="450" height="400"></iframe>
```

to the page template file.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in DaDaBIK (dadabik.org) which automatically creates a CRUD app and allows the embedding in a Wordpress page.